# How to print this diamond pattern using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print this pattern in python:(10 rows rhombus increment-decrement numbers)

```
         1
        121
       12321
      1234321
     123454321
    12345654321
   1234567654321
  123456787654321
 12345678987654321
1234567891987654321
 12345678987654321
  123456787654321
   1234567654321
    12345654321
     123454321
      12321
       121
        1
```

Note : 1234321 is missing in the last but fourth line, so I think it is not a perfect rhombus. Plus instead of 10, 1 is printed in the tenth line.How to achieve this shape? Please let me know.

I had no idea on how to do this using numbers so,tried the below basic program using * but I don't know how to print the same using numbers as shown above.

```
n=11
for i in range(n):
    print(''*(n-i-1)+'* '*(i+1))
for j in range(n-1,0,-1):
    print(''*(n-j)+'* '*(j))
```

Also this prints half the shape only

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * 
* * * 
* * 
*
```

How to print the pattern I mentioned(using increment-decrement numbers)?
Plus is the question wrong because it misses 1234321 line or it can be achieved?
Please help me.I am new to coding so how to achieve this using the simplest way i.e using looping constructs like for loop? Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do a function for one line, and run it twice, skipping the 4 at the end:

```py
def oneline(i):
    for j in range(i,10):
        print(' ', end='')
    for j in range(1, i+1):
        print(j if j<10 else 1, end='')
    for j in range(i-1, 0, -1):
        print(j if j<10 else 1, end='')
    print()

for i in range(1,11):
    oneline(i)
for i in range(9,0,-1):
    if i == 4:
        continue
    oneline(i)
```

Output:

```
         1
        121
       12321
      1234321
     123454321
    12345654321
   1234567654321
  123456787654321
 12345678987654321
1234567891987654321
 12345678987654321
  123456787654321
   1234567654321
    12345654321
     123454321
       12321
        121
         1
```

Comment: Thank you so much:) How to proceed with this in case I want the line 1234321 to be printed? I tried but I couldn't get that line.

Comment: Just remove the `if i == 4: continue`, which I put there to produce what I thought was your desired output.

Comment: Okay,got it. Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possibility for how to generate the geometry:

```
n = 11
for i in range(n // 2 + 1):
    print(' ' * (n // 2 - i) + '* ' * (i + 1))
for i in reversed(range(n // 2)):
    print(' ' * (n // 2 - i) + '* ' * (i + 1))

     * 
    * * 
   * * * 
  * * * * 
 * * * * * 
* * * * * * 
 * * * * * 
  * * * * 
   * * * 
    * * 
     *
```

EDIT: Here is an actual implementation with numbers, that fails at n = 10, unfortunately.

```
from itertools import chain
n = 9
ranges = chain(range(n), reversed(range(n - 1)))
for i in ranges:
    print('  ' * (n - i - 1), *[x + 1 for x in range(i + 1)],
          *[x + 1 for x in reversed(range(i))])
                 1
               1 2 1
             1 2 3 2 1
           1 2 3 4 3 2 1
         1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
       1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
       1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1
         1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
           1 2 3 4 3 2 1
             1 2 3 2 1
               1 2 1
                 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would be more pythonic:

```
size    = 10
pattern = (size-1)*" " + size*"123456789"            # indented pattern
rhombus = [ pattern[i:i+size] for i in range(size) ] # top-left
rhombus = [ d+d[-2::-1] for d in rhombus ]           # horizontal mirror 
rhombus = rhombus+rhombus[-2::-1]                    # vertical mirror
```

*The approach leverages the horizontal and vertical symmetry of the output by only generating the top-left corner and then mirroring horizontally and vertically*

output:

```
for line in rhombus: print(line)                 

         1         
        121        
       12321       
      1234321      
     123454321     
    12345654321    
   1234567654321   
  123456787654321  
 12345678987654321 
1234567891987654321
 12345678987654321 
  123456787654321  
   1234567654321   
    12345654321    
     123454321     
      1234321      
       12321       
        121        
         1
```

Alternatively, if you want to print as you go, you can work with the left side of the pattern for all the lines and print the horizontally mirrored substring of the pattern for each line:

```
size = 10
pattern = size*" " + size*"123456789"         # indented pattern (1 based)
for i in range(1,size*2):                     # for each line (1 based)
    line = pattern[size-abs(size-i):][:size]  # left side of line 
    print(line + line[-2::-1])                # print mirrored line
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple version using for loops. Should work for large numbers.

```
def r(upper=10):
  for i in range(-1 * (upper-1), upper):
    j = upper - abs(i)
    print(' ' * (abs(i)), end ='')
    for k in range(-1 * (j-1), j):
      print(str(j - abs(k))[0], end='')
    print()  


r(10)
```

..

```
         1
        121
       12321
      1234321
     123454321
    12345654321
   1234567654321
  123456787654321
 12345678987654321
1234567891987654321
 12345678987654321
  123456787654321
   1234567654321
    12345654321
     123454321
      1234321
       12321
        121
         1
```

Hope it helps :)